# How to display row index in Ag-Grid in opposite dirrection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I need to display row index for Ag-grid table.
My problem is that it numerates first item on the top of grid as Nr 1.
But i need ag grid to numerate first item with larges number and item at the bottom oldest one with Nr 1.
I was looking a lot on documentation, but havent found any smart solution.
I could write my own cell renderer here but i think it would be wrong and complicated way of doing so.
Does anyone knows is it possible to do something with value getter to make it count in opposite direction?

```
<AgGridColumn
  headerName={'Nr'}
  field="i"
  width={50}
  lockPosition={true}
  valueGetter='node.rowIndex+1' 
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<AgGridColumn
          headerName={'Nr'}
          field="i"
          width={50}
          lockPosition={true}
          valueGetter={inverseRowCount}
        />
```

JS:

```
const inverseRowCount = (params) => {
    return params.api.getDisplayedRowCount() - params.node.rowIndex;
  };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-42qp1d?file=index.js).